# freeing up memory from a struct gives invalid pointer

Tags: c

I am writing some experimental code, to get better at C,
I wrote below code

```
/*This is a test code. Some of the checks are not performed.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person {
    char *name;
    char *occupation;
    int age;
};

typedef struct person prn;

int main(void)
{
    prn *ptr=NULL;
    ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));//a node size of prn is created. No need to do malloc(sizeof(prn)) as variable also have same type.
    ptr->name = malloc(sizeof(ptr->name) * ( strlen("Mrigendra") + 1));//
    ptr->occupation = malloc( sizeof( ptr->occupation) * (strlen("SoftwareE")+1) );

    ptr->name = "Mrigendra";//should use memcpy.
    ptr->occupation = "SoftwareE";
    ptr->age = 20;

    printf("%s\n", ptr->name);
    printf("%s\n", ptr->occupation);
    printf("%d\n", ptr->age);

    free(ptr->occupation);
    free(ptr->name);
    free(ptr);
    return 0;

}
```

On executing above program I get this error

```
Mrigendra
SoftwareE
20
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000040076e ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am in this thinking that ptr is pointing to a location on heap. 
Also its members are also pointers and pointing to the heap, so I freed members and then free the ptr.

1.One thing come to my mind is that 'age' is also on heap and I haven't freed it. Is this the reason?

2.What is the correct way to debug it?
(I have a fear its a dumb question or something obvious I missed)

3."core is dumped" where?

Comment: Your allocation code is really weird. Why are you multiplying by size of pointer? Change it to `sizeof(*ptr)` and other places too. You want the size of pointee instead.

Comment: `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));` is wrong. That allocates either 4 or 8 bytes (the size of a pointer). You need to allocate `sizeof(prn)`, just like your comment says.

Comment: Yes, ptr is not a prn, it's a pointer to a prn. Those are very different things. And yes, you should use memcpy() or strcpy() to assign the string members, because allocating memory for them and then assigning them to a string constant is an instant memory leak.

Comment: `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));//a node size of prn is created. No need to do malloc(sizeof(prn)) as variable also have same type.` This is off the wall, use `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));`. But why allocate memory for a single `struct` unless you plan to reallocate later for more capacity?

Comment: What tool chain are you using?  Other's have told you what's wrong with your code, but you should step into it with a debugger and actually look at what it is doing.  You need to dump the locals at each step.

Comment: That typedef is confusing.  'ptr' looks like 'prn' at a glance.   Don't typedef to save a few chars of typing at the expense of clarity/readabilty.  If you do, you greatly increase the chances of silly errors, eg.  'ptr' instead of 'prn' in malloc sizing:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr))` should be `ptr = malloc(sizeof(prn))` in order to allocate enough memory to hold an object of type `struct person`. `sizeof(ptr)`, in contrast, would always be `8` (the size of a pointer value on a 64 bit system).

Second, `ptr->name = malloc(sizeof(ptr->name) * ( strlen("Mrigendra") + 1));` should be `ptr->name = malloc(strlen("Mrigendra") + 1)` in order to allocate exactly the memory to hold the string `Mrigendra` + the string termination character.

Third, instead of `ptr->name = "Mrigendra"`, which lets `ptr->name` point to a string literal, use `strcpy(ptr->name,"Mrigendra")`. Otherwise, you will later `free` a pointer to a string literal, which is undefined behaviour.

Note: instead of `malloc` + `strcpy`, most systems offer a function `ptr->name=strdup("Mrigendra")`, which does an appropriate malloc and the strcpy in one function.

Comment: will 'age' variable also be freed when I will free memory for ptr?

Comment: yes, `free(ptr)` will free the complete `struct person`-object, which consists of two pointer values and one int value.

Answer (score 4):

C-string assignment does not work with the `=` operator.

```
ptr->name = "Mrigendra";
```

In this line, the `char[]` literal decays to a `char*` and then that pointer is assigned to `ptr->name`. The same is true for the rest of your assignments. The memory you `malloc`ed is leaked here.

When you reach the `free` statements in your code, you attempt to free the address of the string literals, not the memory you allocated earlier.

To get around this, use a function that properly copies the content like

```
strcpy(ptr->name, "Jane");
```

---

I missed a second mistake. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48753705/4341534) answer for an explanation. As [C_Elegans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6141656/c-elegans) points out

> `sizeof(ptr)` needs to be changed to `sizeof(*ptr)`

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(ptr)` needs to be changed to `sizeof(*ptr)`. `sizeof(ptr)` only returns the size of a pointer on your machine, so when you set the members of the struct you're getting a heap overflow and probably writing over `malloc`'s bookkeeping information.

Answer (score 2):

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(ptr));
```

The above line of code will not allocate enough memory for the `struct`, you should use instead:

```
ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));
```

or similar.

You allocate memory for the `struct` pointers, but then, you overwrite their values by assigning string literals to them, losing the addresses of the allocated memory.

So, now you have memory leak, and when you try to call `free()` upon them, you have undefined behavior. You should use functions like `strcpy()` or `memcpy()` to copy strings, not the assignment operator `'='`.